# I can not put photo in a field blob maysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, react-native

how are you? I am trying to put a photo in a database ..
the photo comes in base64 for the php code, which is sent via react-native
already checked and yes the image is on base 64.

code that sends base64:

```
  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options,(response) => {
            if(response.uri){

                let uri = response.uri.replace('file://','');

                RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uri,'base64')
                .then((data)=> {
                    let image  = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+response.data;
                    state.dados[0].foto = response.data;
                    state.imgTmp = image;


                    return RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob.build(data,{type:"image/jpeg;BASE64"});
                })
```

state.dados[0].foto = response.data here is the base64 of the image

php code that saves the image, the code below base64_decode is what it was supposed to work sending the image to the bank ... but it doesn't send.

I put a picture of the code in base64
[image]

'foto' is the base64 image

```
 $foto = base64_decode($dados->dados[0]->foto);
                 //$dataIniciacao = $data->dados[0]->Data_Iniciacao;
                 //$idGrau = $data->dados[0]->IDGrau;
                 //$Data_SessaoElevacao = $data->dados[0]->Data_SessaoElevacao;
                 //$Data_SessaoExaltacao = $data->dados[0]->Data_SessaoExaltacao;
                 $NomeSimbolico = $dados->dados[0]->NomeSimbolico;
                 $email  = $dados->dados[0]->Email;
                 //$login = $data->dados[0]->login;
        $sql = "UPDATE irmaos SET Nome='$nome',Data_Nascimento='$Data_Nascimento',Tratamento='$tratamento',
                 CPF='$cpf',RG='$rg',Telefone='$Telefone',Nacionalidade='$nacionalidade',CidadeNatal='$cidadenatal',Cidade=
                 '$cidade',Empresa='$empresa',
                 emp_Cep='$cepEmpresa',emp_Logradouro='$logradouro',emp_Endereco='$empresaEndereco',emp_Complemento=
                 '$empresaComplemento',emp_Numero='$empresaNumero',emp_Cidade='$empresaCidade',
                 emp_Estado='$empresaEstado',emp_Site='$empresaSite',emp_Telefone='$empresaTelefone',emp_Ramal='$empresaRamal',
                 emp_Fax='$empresaFax',emp_E_mail='$empresaEmail',NomeSimbolico='$NomeSimbolico',Cargo='$cargo',emp_especializacao='$especializacao',
                Email='$email',RelacaoEmprego='$relacaoEmprego',Foto='$foto'
                  where ID_Irmao='$idIrmao'";
                 $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                 $sql->execute();
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. You're not preparing the statement properly, or binding the parameters at all. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Once it's done properly, **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: Remove every field in the query but the image.  Does it still fail?

Comment: Hey guys, i use firebase storage and just upload the image normally without convert it to base64 so what's benefits of convert it first then upload it?

Comment: Guys I know the code is bad but please ask that focus, I do not really know what happens it saves the image sun 4 bytes which is almost nothing, when I require the image again it comes up to 10 base words64